# Передача переменных из функции

Tags: php

Есть ли в PHP способ передать переменные из функции в ту область видимости, в который она была вызвана?
Я понимаю, что есть `return`, но меня интересует просто установка внешней переменной из функции (и кроме `$GLOBALS`).

Comment: а чем обычные методы не устраивают? Например <? global $a; $a+=$b; ?> в самой функции

Comment: @zenith, просто интересно. Можно и через `return`, конечно.  
А вот `$GLOBALS` вообще неудобно.

Comment: Ну так можно указать облость видимости переменной, когда вызыаешь ей в функции. Есл я не прав закидайте меня ананасами.

Comment: @zenith, как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Способов несколько:

1. Через `$GLOBALS`. (хотя вам не нравится)
2. Через `global $param`. (вам почему-то тоже не понравился)
3. Через `return array('param' => $param)` и его разбор.
4. Через передачу функции параметров как ссылок: `function a(&$param){$param = 123;}`.

Я что-то забыл?

Comment: Стоп, №2 - это же для проведения переменной ВНУТРЬ фукции, не? Или оно создаёт внутри ссылку на внешнюю? Мне надо именно изнутри изменить внешнюю.